# Thai chanting in roman letters and translated

Tags: translation, chanting, chant, thai

I bow to you with hopes of happiness, peace, safety and health for you.

And I come with a dire need for help! I am a practicing buddhist and I regularly visit a thai temple for chanting but I know no thai and they don't have their chanting written in roman alphabet and with translation so I can understand and chant.

I have recorded the whole chanting and provide a link to the recording here.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gxmUWA7XxR7OjhOZYXbPA6MxZvsP84kR/view?usp=sharing

Could anyone please provide me or refer me to the chanting written in thai with roman alphabet letters ***and*** an english translation? If you provide me with links then could you please point out the exact parts of the texts that correspond to this chanting?

This would be of great help to me because I can finally understand what we're saying and feel a greater connection to the teachings and to my fellow Sangha-members.

Full of gratitude I bow.

Comment: My pali isn't that great, but it sounds a lot like [Homage to the Triple Gem.](https://buddhaguna-chant.blogspot.com/2011/12/chant-to-overcome-depression-fear-panic.html) There are many variations of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chanting of the ancient Buddhism and present Mahavihara Theravada  is for  memorizing and revisit the practices again and again until getting the understanding to practice perfectly and reaching the   mundane and super mundane attainment concentration (Lokiya-Appana Bhavana and Lokuttara Appana Bhavana). After that, the Buddhist still chant to revisit the way to teach by the buddha  and to be a model for previous Buddhist.

Some chants are for building the **encouragement** to practice for attaining the concentration follow the Buddha such as "Itipiso Bhagava (Buddhanussati)" **because the meaning of them are very deep in detail**. The detail of is an **enlightenment** which has the perfect  relations like Abhidhamma which is big data), so the practitioner will can't understand them easily at first. However, chanting still helpful without understanding because when the practitioner can't practice follow the Dhamma perfectly, if they can't remember the teaching, except they don't want to be perfect like the Sanga. And the practitioner can accumulate  the wholesome trust while chanting as well. It is one of five elements to get the attainment.

(This should be the first: http://chanting-book-for-buddha.blogspot.com/2013/04/5-aradhana-tisarana-pancasila-request.html)

00:00 [https://dharmaforliving.wordpress.com/2016/03/09/chapter-1-morning-evening-chanting-ทำวัตรเช้า-เย็น](https://dharmaforliving.wordpress.com/2016/03/09/chapter-1-morning-evening-chanting-%E0%B8%97%E0%B8%B3%E0%B8%A7%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%A3%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%8A%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%B2-%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%A2%E0%B9%87%E0%B8%99)

http://chanting-book-for-buddha.blogspot.com/2013/03/chanting-book.html

02:00 http://chanting-book-for-buddha.blogspot.com/2013/04/itipiso.html

03:43 http://chanting-book-for-buddha.blogspot.com/2013/04/bahum-jayamangala-gatha-eight-victories.html

07.45 http://chanting-book-for-buddha.blogspot.com/2013/04/jaya-gatha-victory-protection.html

10.15 https://www.dhammatalks.org/books/ChantingGuide/Section0018.html

12.45 It is the pali about giving gifts to the Sanha. I think this chant is  using only in thailand. The other countries may use something different.

Comment: Bonn I give you my apologizes for a very late reply from me. Thank you for your help, kindness and effort.